# Auto Fill Access table with Update query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an access table with below columns

```
Id  process

1   Lotus

2   
3   
4   Rose

5   
6   
7   
8   Lilly

9   
10
```

I am looking for an update query, which can have fuctionality same line filldown in excel.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim Rs As Recordset, strSQL As String, CurData As Variant
'Note: Set a reference to the Microsoft DAO Object library via Tools | References

'Amend this to indicate the table and sort by the autonumber id
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE"

'Opens a recordset (like a query) to the table
Set Rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)


'Loop through the records in the table and if the previous row didnt have data in the
'Repaired_By field then populate the previous Repaired_By data. Assumes the first record is
'populated with info
Rs.MoveLast
Rs.MoveFirst
Do
    If Rs!CONTACT_ID = "" Or IsNull(Rs!CONTACT_ID) Then
        'This field is blank so populate the info from the variable
        Rs.Edit
        Rs!CONTACT_ID.Value = CurData
        Rs.Update
    Else
        'This field isnt blank so store the info in the variable in case the next record is blank
       CurData = Rs!CONTACT_ID.Value
    End If
    Rs.MoveNext
Loop While Not Rs.EOF

'Remove the recordset object from memory
Rs.Close
Set Rs = Nothing
End Sub
```